# Pinescript session.ismarket true during premarket

Tags: pine-script

Plotting lines in pinescript for prior days highs and lows is creating an issue for premarket levels. If I am looking at a chart in NYSE premarket (before 9.30am ET) I need to look at 'today's' values. At 9.30, these become yesterdays values.

However using `session.ismarket` in premarket is producing a TRUE result, and give me the levels for `high[1]`, which is in fact the high from 2 days ago.

I have also tried if `session.ismarket and timeframe.change('D')`, but get the same result

What is the correct way?

```
// Premarket Levels
pdh_o = high[0]
pdl_o = low[0]
pdt_o = time[0]

// Regular levels
if session.ismarket
    pdh_o := high[1]
    pdl_o := low[1]
    pdt_o := time[1]
```

EDIT: I have tried the following:

```
// Regular levels
t =  time(timeframe.period, "1430-2100:23456")
if session.ismarket  and t
    pdh_o := high[1]
    pdl_o := low[1]
    pdt_o := time[1]
```

And while this does work, it produces an error message

```
 The `expr1` parameter of the `operator and` function accepts a 'bool' argument. To avoid potential unexpected results, pass a 'bool' value or expression to this parameter.
```

Comment: it's not an error, it's a warning

Comment: `if session.ismarket  and t` - where `session.ismarket` is a bool value, and `t` is int. `t` is always true except when it is zero

Comment: `and t` makes no sense because it is always true

Comment: `if session.ismarket  and  not na(t)` - this is makes sense